# How to align the top lines of two DIVs?

Tags: css, html

I want the top lines of two DIVs (`<div></div>`) to be aligned horizontally, how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In response to "is there another way to do it", sure you could use `display: inline` but you have a bunch of hacks to remember to get it to work in IE6/7. This way is generally better (but it all comes down to the individual circumstances)

```
<style type="text/css">
    .keeper {
        overflow: hidden; /* expand to contain floated children */
    }

    .keeper div {
       width: 200px;
       height: 30px;
       float: left;
       border-top: 1px solid red; /* so you can see the 'tops' */
    }
  </style>  
    <div class="keeper">
       <div>
       </div>
       <div>
       </div>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 9):

[Steven](https://stackoverflow.com/users/202335/steven),

In addition to [T. Stone](https://stackoverflow.com/users/111375/t-stone)'s suggestion to float both divs, a simple way to align two divs is to make both have the `display: inline-block;` CSS rule and give the lower div the `vertical-align: top;` CSS rule.

Take a look at this simple [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/matthew1/ge2Rp/) example to see how this works.

```
div {
    display: inline-block;
}
div#tall {
    height: 4em;
}
div#short {
    height: 2em;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Comment: Upvoted this because it does not use float:left which makes the parent div short.

Comment: @VinceYuan To keep the parent div from collapsing when its contents consist of floating elements add `overflow: auto;` to the parent. The parent will stretch to fit the contents :)

Answer (score 0):

Float them in a container.

```
.parent div { float: left; width: 50%; }

<div class="parent">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
</div>
```

*Note:*  The sum of the width of the child `div`s can not be greater than 100% of the parent `div`, including `margin` and `padding`.

**Alternative**

If maintaining flow with the page isn't a requirement, and all that really matters is aligning, them, the divs can always be positioned absolutely.

```
.abs { position: absolute; top: 100px; width: 50px; }
.left { left: 0px; }
.right { left: 50px; }

<div class="abs left">1</div>
<div class="abs right">2</div>
```

Comment: Is there another way to do it?