# Why do both inline-block elements fall down in the following case?

Tags: html, css

I have two inline-blocks elements (which are side by side). When I set top margin of one of them, **both** move. Why?

**[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xxw51aLo/1/)**

HTML

```
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

CSS

```
div {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    display: inline-block
}
div:first-child {
    background: #279B61;
    margin-top: 3em
}
div:last-child {
    background: #CC3333
}
```

Comment: Add your code directly to the question, a link alone is not good enough

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to align the top lines of two divs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2040130/how-to-align-the-top-lines-of-two-divs)

Comment: The character limit is generous enough that you do not need a URL shortener. If you're simply using it to circumvent the system, please don't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default `vertical-align` causes the bottom of the elements to line up.

If you push one down, it increases the height of the line they both sit on.

Use `vertical-align: top` (for example) to change that.

Answer (score 0):

Because the default vertical alignment of inline elements is baseline. Setting `vertical-align:top` will pull the second div back up.

```
div {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/xxw51aLo/3/)**